# Real Application of left shift << and right shift >> operators

Tags: logic, operators, programming-languages

What background we have to know about <<  and >> operators and what kind of problem they solves. So I can start thinking of solving my future problems using them.

When ever I see the code/logic which contains those operators. I will start avoiding code/logic. I seen them mostly in audio or video processing libraries.

Please help me get out of my fear on them.

Answer (score 2):

Shift operators are more efficient on hardware. They are essentially specialized multiplication and division - both multiplication and division can be quite expensive on an FPGA or an ASIC. To an extent, using the shift operators to replace multiplication and division in your programs will require some adroit design decisions.

> When ever I see the code/logic which contains those operators. I will start avoiding code/logic. I seen them mostly in audio or video processing libraries.

Video and audio processing basically depend on binary data to be feasible. `>>` and `<<` can be a more natural way of looking at operations on the underlying bits.

Answer (score 1):

One immediate use for these is multiply-by-two.  It used to be that it was faster to left-shift than to multiply by two, so it's a performance technique (probably one of the reasons it's being used in video processing).

I've recently started using it to define flags in my C# code, to help show that they are, in fact, bit flags:

```
[Flags]
enum myFlags {
  undefined = 0,
  smallest = 1,
  next_smallest = smallest << 1
}
```

Comment: That's when, number << 1 but what if you do number << 3. Its not definitely multiplying by 2. Question is what are the situations where we use. Thanks for Ur answer

Comment: Actually, since 1 << 3 is the same as 1 << 1 << 1 << 1, or 2*2*2.  It's actually multiplying by 2^3!  And down at the machine-language level, that's a single cycle execution (1 << 3) instead of at least three cycles (((1*2) *2) *2).